# How to validate a text in selenium where multiple spaces in between two words?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

I would like to know how to write the Xpath for validate the text -'Confirm Passowrd*' where there is more than 10 space gap between two words
[image]

When I tried to get it using chropath tool it gives Xpath like

```
//label[contains(text(),'Confirm                            Password*')]
```

But even that is also not working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use the **normalize-space** in xpath.

```
//label[@ng-if='add_user' and normalize-space(text())='Confirm Password*']
```

Comment: Thanks, This is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You can also get text by:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[@ng-if='add_user']")).GetAttribute("innerText");
```

OR

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[@ng-if='add_user']")).GetAttribute("value");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label").GetAttribute("value");
```